# Completely delete a repository with SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I have a repository at `http://svn.mysite/MySite/`. I used the Apache command line to delete it using `rm -rf MySite/`, and the directory disapeared, but I can still do checkouts from this repo.

How do I completely delete it, so I can start a new empty repository at the same adress that starts at revision 0?

Comment: I can't tell you the site's name unfortunatly. My site is hosted on dreamhost, this is why I chose svn, it comes already installed. I know git is better but what do you want... Yes I have a remote ssh access to the server's shell. I first created the repo using the dreamhost interface.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the advantages of Git has nothing to do with this question.  I love Git but hardselling like this is not helping the OP in any way.

Comment: Git has nothing to do with the question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Command Line:

- svn delete http://svn.mysite/MySite/ --message "Unused"

2) GUI:

- Get a version of [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) and install it.
- You need to have a permission to delete the repository
- Right-Click anywhere on desktop > TortoiseSVN > Repo-Browser
- Manually delete your target in this folder tree

Answer (score 2):

Have you deleted it on the server or just your *working copy*? You need to physically remove the repository on the server.